# How to prevent PHP excel import from removing leading zero in a column?

Tags: php, excel, import

I tried a tutorial here in https://phppot.com/php/import-excel-file-into-mysql-database-using-php/ to import XLSX file to my database (using PHP)

But the problem is, if the column value started with leading zero, after import, I found out that the leading zero was removed.

How to prevent this?

By the way, my phpmyadmin table for that particular column to be imported is structured as Text column, not integer

I've tried adding '' to treat the file as string but shows no success

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","test","phpsamples");
require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{

  $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];

  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);

        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);

        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());

        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
        {
            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);

            foreach ($Reader as $Row)
            {

                $name = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[0]);
                }

                $description = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[1]);
                }

                if (!empty($name) || !empty($description)) {
                    $query = "insert into tbl_info(name,description) values('".$name."','".$description."')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                    if (! empty($result)) {
                        $type = "success";
                        $message = "Excel Data Imported into the Database";
                    } else {
                        $type = "error";
                        $message = "Problem in Importing Excel Data";
                    }
                }
             }

         }
  }
  else
  { 
        $type = "error";
        $message = "Invalid File Type. Upload Excel File.";
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, have you double-checked that leading zero is actually there in the original XLSX? Secondly, according to your link you are using [nuovo/spreadsheet-reader](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader). That library relies on a [third-party library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-excel-reader/) to parse XLSX files. Both libraries are abandoned and bug-ridden. The latter is even hosted in Google Code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a leading apostrophe (only if `$description` starts with a `0`, of course), it will force Excel to read the cell as a text.

```
if ($description[0] === '0') {
    $description = "'" . $description;
}
```

Comment: I will try now and test the import, will give feedback if it is not successful